# Application.kt error Unresolved reference: setPluginRegistrant

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get `Unresolved reference: setPluginRegistrant` error when I try to add the below code in the Application.kt file:

Code causing the issue:
`FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService.setPluginRegistrant(this);`

My Application.kt file:

```
package com.application.test

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService;

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService.setPluginRegistrant(this); //this line is the issue
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine(this));
    }
}
```

Without this line, the code compiles but I get the following leak via LeakCanary:

```
io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.
    ​     FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService received Service#onDestroy() callback)
```

In both cases the background messages work without a problem but I do also get the following messages in the Logcat:

```
W/FLTFireMsgService: A background message could not be handled in Dart as no onBackgroundMessage handler has been registered.
W/FirebaseMessaging: Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name="com.application.test.Application"
        android:label="Test App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.application.test.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/notification_color" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
    </application>
```

Any suggestion how to fix the issue?